# Is there a way to edit files from remote SSH servers with a local editor?

Tags: ssh, text-editor, iterm2

I am wondering if anyone implemented a transparent way of editing text files locally.

As SSH supports SCP it means that it should be able to have a smart terminal which would be able to allow you to use a local editor to edit a remote file.

I am not thinking of methods of mounting drives locally, I am looking for a solution that could work only via your terminal (like iTerm2) and maybe with some help from the the remote server.

On linux is easy to configure your prefered editor and this preferred editor is a smart script that detects if you are in a terminal that supports remote-edit, would trigger that instead of one of the server provided editors.

Have anyone tried and maybe succesfully managed to implement this?

For example I know that iTerm support download and upload of files so why not going a step further.

Comment: You are asking how to do this in Linux, not Windows. Is this correct?

Comment: The editor doesn't matter and in fact I am interested about a solution that would work on OS X via iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I'd like to say there are plenty of editors which are capable of remote editing, i.e. starting an editor on your local machine and editing a file on a remote sever. To name a few: Emacs, UltraEdit.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question right: this assumes that the editor is on your machine, this has to be something facilitated by a smart terminal client, otherwise it cannot work. In the end it doesn't matter which editor it is on the machine because the terminal has to silently download the file and upload it back when is closed.